# Weird behavior of multithread random numbers generator

Tags: c#, random, plinq

Please check below code, this code try to compute birthday conflict possibility. To my surprise, if i execute those code with sequence, the result is expected around 0.44; but if try on PLinq, the result is 0.99.
Anyone can explain the result?

```
    public static void BirthdayConflict(int num = 5, int people = 300) {

        int N = 100000;

        int act = 0;
        Random r = new Random();

        Action<int> action = (a) =>     { 
            List<int> p = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < people; i++)
            {
                p.Add(r.Next(364) + 1);
            }

            p.Sort();

            bool b = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {

                if (i + num -1 >= people) break;

                if (p[i] == p[i + num -1])
                    b = true;
            }

            if (b)
                Interlocked.Increment(ref act);
               // act++;

        };


        // Result is around 0.99 - which is not OK
       // Parallel.For( 0, N, action);

        //Result is around 0.44 - which is OK
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            action(0);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(act / 100000.0);

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a shared (between threads) instance `System.Random`. **It's not thread-safe** then you're getting wrong results (well actually it just doesn't work and it'll return 0). From MSDN:

> If your app calls Random methods from multiple threads, you must use a synchronization object to ensure that only one thread can access the random number generator at a time. If you don't ensure that the Random object is accessed in a thread-safe way, calls to methods that return random numbers return 0.

Simple (but not so efficient for parallel execution) solution is to use a lock:

```
lock (r)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < people; i++)
    {
        p.Add(r.Next(364) + 1);
    }
}
```

To improve performance (but you should measure) you may use multiple instances of `System.Random`, be careful to initialize each one with a different seed.

Comment: Jon Skeet has a [nice article](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness.aspx) about implementing performant thread-safe `Random`.

Answer (score -1):

I find a useful explanation [why random does not work under multi-thread](http://java-performance.info/java-util-random-java-util-concurrent-threadlocalrandom-multithreaded-environments/), although it was original for Java, still can be benefitical.